# VC++: non-global old-style function declarations?

Tags: c++

In Visual Studio 2003 using pure C, old-style function
declarations do not show as global member
i.e. void func(blah) int blah;{...}

This shows as a global member in the members dropdown:

```
void func(int blah)
{
    ...
}
```

This compiles, but old-style does not appear in the global
members dropdown:

```
void func(blah)
int blah;
{
    ...
}
```

I am trying to use the new 'Calling Graph' functionality to
analyse code, but as most of our legacy code uses the 
old-style function parameters, those functions are not
recognized are not shown as Global Members, and therefore do
not appear in the 'Calling Graph'.

Is there any way to let the "call graph" analysis process
old-style function declarations correctly?

Comment: I guess he asks for pieces of advice on how to make the 'old style' function be recognized and analyzed by Calling Graph, it's obvious. It's not because his question doesn't have a "?" that it's not a question, therefor he doesn't deserve downvotes. +1

Comment: I did not downvote the question. Just wanted to point out that the 'question' might be a bit vague.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I didn't word the 'Question' correctly, but hopefully the added explanation sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to consider to just change the old style function signatures. There shouldn't be any issues with that.

**EDIT:**

For an automatic conversion of your source files from old style syntax to ANSI-C style, take a look at the [cproto](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/cproto.htm) tool. Maybe that could save you some time if you decide to go that direction.

This is an excerpt from the docs:

> -f n
>       Set the style of generated function prototypes where n is a
>   number from 0 to 3. For example,
>   consider the function definition
>
> ```
> main (argc, argv)
> int argc;
> char *argv[];
> {
> }
> ```
>
> If the value is 0, then no prototypes are generated. When set to
>   1, the output is:
>
> ```
> int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/);
> ```
>
> For a value of 2, the output has the form:
>
> ```
> int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[]);
> ```
>
> The default value is 3. It produces the full function prototype:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately there are 45,000+ function declarations - so I was trying to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe the engine uses regexs to trace routine signatures and the old C style isn't implemented.